# How to create a Expand and Collapse in Data grid

Tags: wpf, linq, wpf-controls

I need to know how can we create a expander and collapse option in datagrid , and also how to sorting on the header cell click.i'm a newbie to wpf, but i have knowledge on linq.

Comment: What exactly would you need to expand? further rows or some kind of content panel. Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView

Comment: Also try : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21986/Collapsible-DataGrid-and-GridView-Control

Comment: The grouped rows and columns

Comment: i believe what you are looking for is Nested GridView Example. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685079/Nested-GridView-in-ASP-NET-using-Csharp